Generalization of Abel's theorem
Let $D$ be a domain on complex plane, $f$ be a regular analytic function on $D.$ We take $a\in D$ and $b\in \partial D$ s.t. for any $t\in (0,1), a+t(b-a)\in D.$
I wondered if we can say that $\lim_{t\uparrow1}f(a+t(b-a))$ converge to some value on $\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Im}f)\subset \mathbb{CP}^1$.
Abel's theorem works well provided that $B(a,|b-a|) \subset D$ ($B(a,|b-a|)$ is a disc centered at $a$ and radius $|b-a|$). But in other case, I have no idea to solve it. I also want to know what happens if we assume that $f$ is bounded. Can someone find a proof or a counterexample?

What if, say, $D$ is the open disk centered at $0$ with radius $1$, $a=0$, $b=1$, and $f(z)=1/(z-1)$?

@JoséCarlosSantos I wanted to mean that $\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Im}f)$ is a closure in a topological space $\mathbb{P}^1$, so your one is not a counterexample. I added the context to the question.
